# Como contar varios registros separados por comas dentro de una misma variable con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, contador

como están.

Tengo una variable que se llama -pos- y allí se guardan datos de esta forma: 1,2

Como puedo hacer para contar esos registros separados por comas. en este caso me deberia decir que hay 2 registros en esa variable ya que son 1,2.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<tr>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Total Posiciones:</font></td> 
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $datosone['pos']?>" name="cambios_kal"></td>
</tr>
```

Debería de imprimir ese conteo que les digo en ese campo.

De que manera podría hacerlo? cualquier comentario me podría ser de utilidad muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separar por la coma con `explode`, el resultado es un `array`, asi que sólo necesitas contar los elementos del `array` resultante.

```
    $pos = "1,2,3";

    echo count(explode(",", $pos));
// resultado 3
```

Comment: muchas gracias, eso era lo que necesitaba hacer. que tengas un excelente día.